# Edit tax percent on edit order page

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

How we can edit tax percent on Edit order page

```
admin panel->sales->orders->view->orderview->edit order
```

[image: Screenshot]

as you can see in the screenshot I've made the tax percent field editable now what I want from this is when the admin clicks the 'Update Items and Qty`s' button the tax percent (Which I made editable) also get updated with ref. to that order and the grand total of that order will be calculated by the updated tax percent.

will appreciate any suggestion to achieve that.

Thanks.